# How to pass external arguments to jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to write a JMeter script which can be used on multiple machines. 
Example :

**stringProp name="Argument.value"**

```
7|0|44|https://${server}:8693/cea/ABC_WebClient/|${randomString}|com.test.server.gui.question
```

**/stringProp**
In above line, i need to pass **server** and **randomString** as an external argument.
How do I pass those values to script? I cannot define them in CSV file or something to pass an argument.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can pass the values to JMeter script via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jserver=localhost -JrandomString=foobarbaz -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. In your .jmx script you can access the values via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

   ```
   7|0|44|https://${__P(server,)}:8693/cea/ABC_WebClient/|${__P(randomString,)}|com.test.server.gui.question
   ```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)